# How to change value of a string in binary tree?

Tags: c, file, tree

This function `update()` should suppose to the this, it scans information from file stream `upd`, number of the PC and its new IP address. It should scan the tree looking for PC's that have same `red_br` and `s_red_br`, and when it finds that PC, should update its IP address with the new IP address (`s_ip_adress`).

`red_br` and `s_red_br` are numbers of a PC; `ip_adresa` is PC's current IP address; `s_ip_adresa` is a new IP address.

RACUNAR is from:

```
typedef struct racunar_st {
    int red_br;
    char naziv[MAX_NAZIV];
    char ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    int brzina;
    struct racunar_st *left;
    struct racunar_st *right;
} RACUNAR;



void update(FILE *upd, FILE *out, RACUNAR *root){
    int s_red_br;   
    char s_ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    while(fscanf(upd, "%d %s", &s_red_br, s_ip_adresa) == 2){
         int temp = root->red_br;          
         char temp1 = *root->ip_adresa;                             
         if (temp == s_red_br){  
             temp1 = *s_ip_adresa; 
         }
    }
}
```

I know that I am not going through the whole tree; I just wanted to test it and I can't even change the root.

Here you go the full program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAZIV 20
#define MAX_VEL 10
#define MAX_IP 14+1

typedef struct racunar_st {
    int red_br;
    char naziv[MAX_NAZIV];
    char ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    int brzina;
    struct racunar_st *left;
    struct racunar_st *right;
} RACUNAR;


void init_tree(RACUNAR **root){
    *root = NULL;
}

void add_to_tree(RACUNAR *new, RACUNAR **root){
    if(*root == NULL){
        *root = new;
    } else if(new->brzina <= (*root)->brzina){
        add_to_tree(new, &((*root)->left));
    } else if(new->brzina > (*root)->brzina) {
        add_to_tree(new, &((*root)->right));
    }
}

RACUNAR *create_new_item(int red_br, char naziv[], char ip_adresa[], int brzina){
    RACUNAR *new = (RACUNAR *)malloc(sizeof(RACUNAR));
    if(new == NULL){
        printf("Nema dovoljno RAM-a!!!\n");
        exit(21);
    }

    new->red_br = red_br;
    strcpy(new->naziv, naziv);
    strcpy(new->ip_adresa, ip_adresa);
    new->brzina = brzina;

    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;

    return new;
}

void read_tree_from(FILE *in, RACUNAR **root){
    int tmp_red_br; 
    char tmp_naziv[MAX_NAZIV];
    char tmp_ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    int tmp_brzina;
    while(fscanf(in, "%d %s %s %d", &tmp_red_br, tmp_naziv, tmp_ip_adresa, &tmp_brzina) != EOF){
        RACUNAR *new = create_new_item(tmp_red_br, tmp_naziv, tmp_ip_adresa, tmp_brzina);
        add_to_tree(new, root);
    }
}

void save_item_to(FILE *out, RACUNAR *x){
    fprintf(
        out, "%d %s %s %d\n",
        x->red_br, x->naziv, x->ip_adresa, x->brzina
        );
}

void save_tree_to(FILE *out, RACUNAR *root){
    if(root != NULL){
        save_tree_to(out, root->left);
        save_item_to(out, root);
        save_tree_to(out, root->right);
    }
}

void destroy_tree(RACUNAR **root){
    if(*root != NULL){
        destroy_tree(&((*root)->left));
        destroy_tree(&((*root)->right));
        free(*root);
        *root = NULL;
    }
}

FILE *safe_fopen(char *filename, char *mode, int error_code){
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, mode);
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Nije moguce otvoriti fajl '%s'\n", filename);
        exit(error_code);
    }

    return fp;
}

void update(FILE *upd, FILE *out, RACUNAR *root){
    int s_red_br;   
    char s_ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    while(fscanf(upd, "%d %s", &s_red_br, s_ip_adresa) == 2){
         int temp = root->red_br;
            printf("%d\n", temp);   // just testing to see if the function read data from file
                printf("%d\n", s_red_br);    
                    printf("%s\n", s_ip_adresa);   
                if ( temp == s_red_br){  
                     *root->ip_adresa = *s_ip_adresa; 
                }
    }   printf("%s\n", root->ip_adresa); // checking if that ip adress has been changed
}

int main(int arg_num, char *args[]) {
    if(arg_num != 4){
        printf("Neispravan poziv programa!\n Pozvati sa: FILENAME_IN FILENAME_UPDATE FILENAME_OUT\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *in_filename = args[1];
    char *update_filename = args[2];
    char *out_filename = args[3];

    FILE *in = safe_fopen(in_filename, "r", 1);
    FILE *upd = safe_fopen(update_filename, "r", 2);
    FILE *out = safe_fopen(out_filename, "w", 3);

    RACUNAR *root;
    init_tree(&root);

    read_tree_from(in, &root);
    update(upd, out, root);
    save_tree_to(out, root);

    destroy_tree(&root);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(upd);
    fclose(out);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `temp1 = *s_ip_adresa;` does not change the value in root->red_br, it changes the local temp copy of the value found in root->red_br.

Comment: Note that binary trees are usually sorted on one or more of the data fields, if those fields are being updated, you really need to do a find, delete and inset operation.

Comment: Yes i know that, they are sorted for there internet speed not on ip adress,  am updating there ip adress and not the speed so the structure of the tree isnt being damaged

Comment: Please post an [MCVE].  I don't see where what you are reading is added to any in-memory tree. The update function seems to read data from a file and  store it in some local variables.

Comment: its has 140lines of code, i dont know if i can post it here ?

Comment: That's what the MCVE is about.  Prune it to the minimal set of code that reproduces your bug.  If that's 100 or 140 lines so be it.  We can't debug your problem if the relevant code is not available to us.  Just put forth and effort to remove as much non-relevant code as you can.

Comment: @jwdonahue just updated and posted the whole program

Comment: @jwdonahue no no i thought i cant post a lot of lines of codes, tought there was a limit for it .Didnt know i could post the whole program.

Comment: Minimal & Complete, doesn't imply everything.  It means just the code that is needed to follow the relevant execution path.  Let me look at this...

Comment: Are you sure that the input file contains a record that would update the root node of the tree?  That is all that this code can currently do, so I wouldn't expect any change if your test input doesn't change the root node.

Comment: Yes it does, it cointains the node its the red_br.

Comment: The red_br?  What value does the root node have?  Are you sure the update file matches that?

Comment: the root->red_br has value of 301 and i on purpose put the same number in update file, the file also has a new ip adress that changes the ip adress a pc with a number 301. But it doesnt change nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt:

Your `update(upd, out, root);` takes an input file, an output file and a pointer to an in-memory binary tree.  Your `save_tree_to(out, root);` takes an output file and a pointer to root.  Make up your mind which of those two functions will write to the file.  Assuming we don't need the output file for `update` and that it can simply make changes within the root data structure, then:

```
void update( FILE *upd, RACUNAR *root )
{
    int s_red_br;
    char s_ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    while ( fscanf( upd, "%d %s", &s_red_br, s_ip_adresa ) == 2 )
    {
        RACUNAR *node = find( s_red_br, root );
        if ( NULL != node )
        {
            strncpy(node->ip_adresa, s_ip_adresa, MAX_IP);
        }
        else
        {
            // Either insert new data or throw some kind of error here.
        }
    }
}
```

Your real problem is the fact that you have data structure that is not sorted by a primary key.  Given a red_br value, you can't find the matching node without searching the entire tree.

```
RACUNAR* find( int red_br, RACUNAR *root )
{
    RACUNAR *node = root;
    while ( NULL != node )
    {
        if ( red_br == node->red_br )
        {
            return node;
        }

        // TODO: Need search code here, basically requires a tree sorted by red_br values.

        node = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: no, nothing, will try that now, just put break after *root->ip_adresa = *s_ip_adresa ?

Comment: Because i have function that prints the tree and the ip adress is still the same

Comment: Will try that now.

Comment: And the FILE *out was a mistake, i forgot to delete it, sry for that

Comment: You will have to do that.  You need to sort your tree on the br_red fields so you can find them quickly.  I would read records into an array and build two binary trees that point to those records, one for br_red and one for brzina.  In other words, take the left and right fields out of the records. You don't need to store that data anway.

Comment: Since the IP addresses are stored in character arrays, you need to replace `*node->ip_adresa = *s_ip_adresa;` with `strcpy(node->ip_adresa, s_ip_adresa)`, don't you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes!  Thanks.